# Outgoing connection limits for Azure App Services regarding resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

My Azure Web App runs on a Windows-S1 App Service Plan and hit a connection limit at 100 connections:

[image]

However, I remember much more generous limits and I could still find [a blog post talking about limits in the thousands for an app service plan](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html).

The only sensible interpretation would be that the generous limit is for all the apps in the plan together and the 100 is per resource group *of the app* (rather than the one of the plan).

But I don't see that explained properly. That the first row in the linked table simply says "unlimited" for the app in the plan doesn't fill me with confidence either. It also would be rather surprising that the resource group of the *app* has such a big impact, I only knew that the one of the *plan* has an impact (it defines the "webspace", an undocumented internal Azure concept).

Can somebody in the know confirm my interpretation or tell me how else to read this?

**EDIT:** If I can trust the connection graphs under "Diagnose and solve problems"/"TCP Connections", I have multiple apps simultaneously that each hit the 100 connections limit:

[image]

At the top of the page where the graph is it does say the data should be per app and indeed the graphs are different for each app.

But all apps are in the same resource group! So I have no idea what the actual limits are. I don't see where a 100 connections per app limit is documented anywhere.

**EDIT2:**

I don't think those graphs can be trusted. The following image shows two of them edited together for two apps in the same resource group and the same plan:

[image]

One app was turned off, on and off again near the end. Yet, the rest of the graphs are identical. This suggests to me that the graph is indeed not per app and merely shows zero when the app it's looked at through is turned off at that time. Really confusing.

Comment: Where do you see it is documented in the App Service limits page? All I can see is 100 plans per resource group which has nothing common with undocumented 100 limit of connections the diagnostic tool is mentioning. As far as I understand, there is limit of 1920 total TCP connections per instance and initial limit of 128 SNAT ports per app. Maybe the undocumented limit is 100 TCP connections per endpoint.

Comment: @kamilz Yes, I can't find it either now - must have been confused. I removed the remark from the question.